# "Have someone + adj" means "make someone + adj?"

Tags: grammar, causatives, causative-have

When I first saw these sentences bellow, I thought they meant *"Have someone +adj around yourself"*,

> You have me sad for most days
>
> They'll have you suicidal

But, when I translated, I saw that it isn't like that, but more like: "You make someone +adj"

Now I am confused. What do those sentence actually mean?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that usage overlaps with "make someone" +adj. Here is a dictionary definition that includes that meaning:
[Oxford Lexico "have" 2.4](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/have)

2.4 Cause (someone or something) to be in a particular state or condition.
Look at the additional example sentences, in particular, this one:
*‘Now her article has me thinking.’*

This applies to your second example sentence.
Your first example sentence doesn't sound quite right, so unless you can point to a source, I won't comment on it.